# C++ How do I return a char array from a function?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use Vigenere Cipher. But when I tried to return my array, there are garbages characters end of my output.

What am I doing wrong?

```
char*   sifrele(char* metin)
{
        char* sifreliMetin = new char[static_cast<int>(strlen(metin))];

        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(metin); i++)
        {
            char sifreliHarf = metin[i] + sifreAtanamisMetin[i] - 64;

            if (sifreliHarf > 90)
                sifreliHarf -= 26;

            sifreliMetin[i] = sifreliHarf; 
        }
        return sifreliMetin;
}
```

and this is the output:

[image]

Metin means text, BTW.

The text is 19 characters but the output is 23. The last 4 are garbage.

Comment: Time to learn about `std::vector<char>` or `std::string`.

Comment: It's a homework. I know it's pointless.

Comment: Also don't use magic numbers.  For instance `if (sifreliHarf > 90)` should be `if (sifreliHarf > 'Z')`

Comment: If you really don't wanna use c++, make sure you terminate the string. I.e., after the for-loop set `sifreliMetin[strlen(metin)] = '\0'`

Comment: @Kaepxer *It's a homework* -- Then you should have been taught about null-termination.

Comment: ...and don't overrun the allocated buffer with an off-by-one error.

Comment: You'll be surprised to learn that there are not 19, but 20 characters in your string. The last character of a C-style string is always `'\0'`, which is not included in what `strlen()` tells you. That's how C-style strings work, and when you are moving them around it is your responsibility to allocate an extra byte for the null byte, and copy it, if needed. The shown code fails to do so.

Comment: Oh, thanks. You helped a lot! I'm new to programming as you can see. Thanks for suggestions. Thanks again.

Comment: `char*   sifrele(char* metin)` -- Now call your function like this: `char * p = sifrele(0);`, and get ready as to why things seem to go wrong, even if you fix your error.

Comment: *It's a homework. I know it's pointless.* -- In this day and age, I wonder why teaching C++ holds onto teaching unsafe and unsecure practices.  You have a potential buffer overrun, potential memory leak, etc. etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining the various comments:

Allocate a buffer with the correct size:

```
char* sifreliMetin = new char[static_cast<int>(strlen(metin) + 1)];
```

Make sure you terminate the string after the for-loop:

```
sifreliMetin[strlen(metin)] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 1):

strlen() doesn't count line end symbol which indicates that the string is over. You should care about '\0' character to point line is over.  So do something like that:

```
char*   sifrele(char* metin)
    {
    int len=strlen(metin);
    char* sifreliMetin = new char[len + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        char sifreliHarf = metin[i] + sifreAtanamisMetin[i] - 64;

        if (sifreliHarf > 90)
            sifreliHarf -= 26;

        sifreliMetin[i] = sifreliHarf; 
    }
    sifreliMetin[len]=0;
    return sifreliMetin;
}
```